Forgetful functor from derived category $D(\mathbb{Z})$ to Spectra
How is concretely defined the (canonical?) forgetful functor from $D(\mathbb{Z})$, the derived category of the ring of integers, to the catetegory of spectra $\text{Sp}$? (here is refered to such map. If I'm not mistaken it is considered there on level of $\infty$-functors)

There are different techniques you can use to get this map, depending on the amount of higher category theory you are familiar with. One fairly conceptual way is as follows: we start with the inclusion $*\to\mathcal{D}_{\geq 0}(\mathbb{Z}), *\mapsto \mathbb{Z}[0]$. Since the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Spc}$ of spaces is freely generated by colimits by $*\in\mathrm{Spc}$, we get a unique cocontinuous functor $C\colon\mathrm{Spc}\to\mathcal{D}_{\geq 0}(\mathbb{Z})$ sending $*$ to $\mathbb{Z}[0]$ via left Kan extension. The functor $C$ sends a space to the singular chain complex associated to it (and then this chain complex to the associated object in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{Z})$). Just like in the $1$-categorical case, the functor $C$ comes automatically with a right adjoint functor $K\colon\mathcal{D}_{\geq 0}(\mathbb{Z})\to\mathrm{Spc}$, which incidentally is the Eilenberg-MacLane space functor. Now we apply the stabilization functor $\mathrm{Sp}(-)$ that takes the category of spectrum objects in a category with finite limits. This gives a pair of functors
$$\mathrm{Sp}(C)\colon\:\mathrm{Sp}:\simeq\mathrm{Sp}(\mathrm{Spc})\rightleftarrows\mathrm{Sp}(\mathcal{D}_{\geq 0}(\mathbb{Z}))\simeq\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{Z})\;\colon\mathrm{Sp}(K)\simeq:H.$$
(This is still an adjunction, for instance because $\mathrm{Sp}(-)$ is an $(\infty,2)$-functor.) The functor $H\colon\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{Z})\to\mathrm{Sp}$ is the canonical functor that they mention. It is the stabilization of the Eilenberg-MacLane space functor, and as such it probably does not come as a surprise that, given an abelian group $A$, $HA$ is the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum of $A$. Moreover, $H$ defines an equivalence $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{Z})\to\mathrm{Mod}_{H\mathbb{Z}}$ towards the $\infty$-category of $H\mathbb{Z}$-module spectra. Under this equivalence, $H\colon\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{Z})\to\mathrm{Sp}$ corresponds to the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Mod}_{H\mathbb{Z}}\to\mathrm{Sp}$ that forgets the $H\mathbb{Z}$-module structure, so that is why $H\colon\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{Z})\to\mathrm{Sp}$ is sometimes called a forgetful functor.
Edit: For reasons of length, I will reply to your comments here.

I indeed do not want to work with a particular model for $\mathrm{Spc}$, but want to work with an ''abstract'' version of it: the $\infty$-cateogry of spaces just has a bunch of properties and structures, and this is all I want to know. In the ideal situation, a model only proves that spaces exist with their expected properties. Compare it to working with the universal property of the tensor product of modules, rather than with an explicit model such as a huge quotient of a huge free module.

The statement that $\mathrm{Spc}$ is freely generated under colimits by $*$ needs $\infty$-categories, because in $1$-category language it is sort of not possible to write down what we actually mean with this: the statement is that, for any cocomplete $\infty$-category $\mathcal{D}$, the ''evaluation at $*$''-functor $\mathrm{ev}_*\colon\mathrm{Fun}^\mathrm{cocont}(\mathrm{Spc},\mathcal{D})\to\mathcal{D}, F\mapsto F(*)$ is an equivalence of $\infty$-categories, where $\mathrm{Fun}^\mathrm{cocont}(-,-)$ denotes the full sub-$\infty$-category of $\mathrm{Fun}(-,-)$ at the functors that preserve all colimits. In other words, you can uniquely (in a homotopical sense) define a cocontinuous functor $\mathrm{Spc}\to\mathcal{D}$ by just saying whereto you map $*\in\mathrm{Spc}$.
The problem with $1$-categories is not so much set-theoretic issues (if I understand what you mean with that correctly), but more that such an inherently homotopical statement (note also that all colimits are homotopy colimits, which are not functorial in a $1$-categorical sense but only in an $\infty$-categorical sense) cannot really be stated without a homotopical language.
There is a $1$-categorical analogue, by the way, of this property of spaces: the $1$-category of sets satisfies the same property among $1$-categories $\mathsf{D}$ with all small colimits. This to illustrate that there are not really set-theoretic issues.

I don't really want to think of $\mathrm{Spc}$ as being a ''blown up $1$-category'', again because this is sort of picking a model for it. There is a process called animation, with a universal property similar to what you are alluding to, and $\mathrm{Spc}$ is the animation of finite sets. This universal property of spaces and of animation are both special cases of what we are using here: given an $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$, the $\infty$-category of space-valued presheaves $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})$ is the free cocompletion of $\mathcal{C}$: any functor $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ towards an $\infty$-category $\mathcal{D}$ with small colimits can be extended uniquely to a functor $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Spc})\to\mathcal{D}$ via left Kan extension. This is again completely analogous to the $1$-categorical situation, once you replace spaces with sets and $\infty$-categories with $1$-categories. So rather than looking at a ''blow-up of a $1$-category'', the ''expansion'' of our $\infty$-categories that is relevant here is taking space-valued presheaves over your $\infty$-category. This is the free cocompletion, and this comes with the universal property that you wrote down.

We need to pass to the $\infty$-world in order for our Kan extensions to be homotopy Kan extensions, so that they exhibit the correct homotopcial behaviour. In the $1$-categorical world, naively taking Kan extensions does not yield the correct results, and taking homotopy Kan extensions (or rather, models of them) in the $1$-world (when e.g. model category structures are floating around) is painful at best and completely impractical at worst.

Lastly, the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Spc}$ does not really extend the $1$-category of CW-complexes. If anything, it is like you are taking homotopy classes of everything, thereby reducing the information present rather than expanding it. However, we are not literally taking homotopy classes, because that would give a $1$-category and lose too much information in order to do actual homotopy theory. The $\infty$-category of spaces on the other hand contains all information about the homotopy theory of spaces, and ''a homotopy theory'' can be defined to mean ''an $\infty$-category''. Put differently, $\mathrm{Spc}$ does not really extend CW-complexes because an object of $\mathrm{Spc}$ does not have points in the same way a CW-complex has those, and you cannot do topology with objects with the objects of $\mathrm{Spc}$. In other words, spaces forget all non-homotopical information still present in topological spaces.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
